# Which sentences mean the same as "My mother drives more carefully than my father."

Tags: writing

1. My mother drives more carefully than my father.
2. My father does not drive as carefully as my mother.
3. My father does not drive so carefully as my mother.
4. My father is a less careful driver than my mother.
5. My father drives less carefully than my mother.

I'd like to know whether all the sentences have the same meaning or not and which sentence is exactly the same as the meaning of the first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

All sentences say the same thing exactly; however, the 3rd sentence would not be grammatically correct and to correct it I would suggest the 2nd sentence.